# SharePoint 2013 WebService and SSO C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint, single-sign-on

I have a SharePoint 2013 WebService and want to use SSO (Single Sign On). The service has been deployed in IIS 15 hive and converted to an application.

[IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4kIO.jpg)

Then I configured web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

Web Service is an asmx file

```
[ScriptService]
public class Services : WebService
{
  [WebMethod]
  public void DoAction() {
  ...
  }
}
```

So…Now I´m logged in windows as an user (let´s say sp\user1). When I run Internet explorer (IE), the IE should run under the same user credentials and when accessing the web service this also should by executed as sp\user1, but there always comes a Login Authentication Required window.

How can I achieve SSO and prevent extra login?

Environment Win2008R2, IIS 7.5, SP2013, C#

[Asked same question on sharepoint.stackexchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137117/sharepoint-2013-webservice-and-sso-c)

Comment: Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the SharePoint 2013 Authentication provider to handle the kerberos token . This can be done from the central admin of SharePoint. Also, You site must send the kerberos token when request by the SHarePoint during authentication.

This [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806870.aspx) will give high level idea about the Windows authenticatication (kerberos) of SHarePoint.

Also, refer http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/09/26/the-first-kerberos-guide-for-sharepoint-2013-technicians/